# NodePort traffic balance works not as expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-nodeport

I have a cluster with 2 nodes:

- Master
- Slave

I have created deployment, which creates 2 pods within the cluster. In my example it looks like:

- Pod1 -> Master
- Pod2 -> Slave

Then I created a `NodePort` service, which should route the traffic in some specific way. I was hoping for

- 50% of the requests to be handled by Pod1
- 50% by Pod2

But unfortunately it does not work this way. It looks like when I request a resource, and I keep requesting (refreshing a page), Pod1 (in the example) is handling the requests. Then, when I wait a bit (i.e. 1 minute) without any requests, and after this time I request the resource Pod2 starts to answer (and again, when I keep refreshing, Pod2 is still handling it).

Is it correct behavior? How can I make NodePort to route trafic in real 50/50 in this case?

Thanks

Comment: >I have created deployment? why two different deployments? how these two different deployments reach by service? one service with and two replica of pods should work

Comment: I recall there being an issue when a Nodeport is called from outside the cluster that the iptables can't perform round-robin. However if you go by the ClusterIP the Load-Balancing should work fine. 
The GitHub issue, maybe its relevant: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67572

Comment: @Adiii, there is 1 deployment, which has 2 replicas

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer was trivial, and not related to kubernetes configuration.

Since I was just using browser to access HTML page, some default HTTP headers was sent by browser. The one, which probably suggested to kubernetes to handle the request on same pod was `Connection: keep-alive`.

Calling `curl` or using `Postman` and deleting the headers works as expected.